# HMVC Ubuntu folder structure and setup

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, codeigniter-hmvc

I'm currently migrating a website to Linux Ubuntu. I have a HMVC website created using Codeigniter on windows. I have installed Xampp on Linux but i cant open my website through localhost to test whether it works or not. Maybe someone can help me how to set up HMVC Codeigniter on Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there might not be any change inside the project while switching from windows to Linux.

- Can you tell me what kind of error you are getting ?
- Have yo set the proper permissions for the project folder like 0755 ?